# R Shiny Bslib Package's Accordion Not Working

Tags: r, shiny

I'm having an issue with an accordion in my Shiny app: despite declaring it correctly it is not working.

I'm trying to use the bslib package's accordion() to create a simple accordion with openable and closeable panels. You can find the documentation for bslib's accordion [here](https://rstudio.github.io/bslib/reference/accordion.html).

This is my code declaring my accordion (in my ui.R file):

```html
div(id="accordion-section-container",
   div(id="bslib-accordion",
        bslib::accordion(
          id="my-accordion", #note: i've tried w/ & w/o id declaration
          bslib::accordion_panel(
            "Title", "Content"
          ),
          bslib::accordion_panel(
            "Title2", "Content"
          ),
          bslib::accordion_panel(
            "Title3", "Content"
          ),
        ),       
    ),
),
```

I believe I am declaring the accordion correctly, however, when I run the app the accordion displays like so:

[image: image of accordion, showing formatting incorrect and not responsive]

The panels do not open or close when clicked and the formatting doesn't seem to be consistent with the bslib package's default.  When I 'inspect' the page, my console displays the following error message:

```html
accordion() requires Bootstrap version 5 but this page is using version 3
(anonymous) @ tag-require.js:11
```

I know that bslib is operating with bootstrap version 3, however, it still offers accordion() as a function. I've made sure that I have the most up to date version of the package (0.5.1).

Why do you think this issue is occurring? Might anyone have any advice for solving this issue?  I've asked another question related to this one about creating an accordion using JQuery instead of bslib, as I haven't been able to get it to work at all with bslib, but also ran into issues. Maybe there is one issue that's causing both accordion-creation methods to not work? I would deeply appreciate any assistance with either of these related questions!

Thank you so much!

**General notes (if helpful):**

**Background/Dependencies:** I'm using the shiny.router package to allow for simple routing between the pages of the app, shinyjs to include javascript (keeping this minimal though as I would like this to be fairly maintainable by someone with R experience and limited web dev knowledge), jquery's library where helpful, and the bslib package.

**Structure:** I have a server.R file with my router logic (ex. buttons linking to other pages), ui.R with my page creation code, and global.R where I run the app. I keep my javascript files in my www folder and have jquery downloaded there as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your `ui.R` you could include the Bootstrap version 5 dependency, but that would get super messy as i'd imagine you'd have 2-3+ different bootstrap css sheets. See if this works:

```
.boot_dep <- "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"

ui <- tagList(
  tags$head(
    tags$link(
      href = .boot_dep, rel = "stylesheet"
    ),
  ...
  )
)
```

Doubt *highly* this will resolve the error being thrown, however.
Strange the library itself flags the conflict on versioning tho... might be another issue.